# Multiple lines of centered text in between curly brackets

Tags: math-mode, brackets

I would like to have several blocks of centered text and math within pairs of tall curly brackets, linked by arrows, similar to the following picture.

[image: curly braces correspondence]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `parbox`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=2in]{geometry}    
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
   \aleph : \left\{ \parbox[c]{1.1in}{\centering
                       Nash components\\with respect to X}
            \right\}
            \rightarrow
            \left\{ \parbox[c]{1.1in}{\centering
                       essential divisors\\over X}
            \right\}
\end{align}
is the \itshape{Nash map}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: One can make the width to be adapted automatically to the content via `\newcommand{\SetWithText}[1]{
\left\{    
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0pt}
 \fbox{\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}
\centering
#1 
\end{varwidth}}
 \right\}
}`. Example of use: `\[
\alpha :
\SetWithText{Test} \longrightarrow  \SetWithText{One billion searches per second $\Rightarrow$ 36 yrs  \\ All this to recover only $10$ bits !}
\]`